# Efficient Way To Get Line from StreamReader which Matches Regex in C#

Tags: c#, stream, streamreader

I have a file, and I want to get the line of the file which matches a regex query.

My code is something like this:

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(EmbeddedResourceGetter).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePath);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);

return file.ReadToEnd()
    .Split('\n').ToList()
    .Find(l => Regex.IsMatch(l, "regex-query-here"));
```

however, I feel like this is quite inefficient and if I need to repeat this multiple times, it can take a long time to complete.

So is there a more efficient way to get a line which matches a regex query without reading the whole file, or will I have to refactor my code in a different way to make it more efficient?

Comment: How large are your files? If you are talking about a couple of hundred lines max, I'd say your code is totally fine

Comment: It appears to take approx. 300ms to read the whole file, which is too long when I run it multiple times.

Comment: Weil, ok :D the alternative I'd see is to read line by line. But I'm not sure if this will give you a huge performance increase - assuming that by average you have to read half the file every time

Comment: Use ReadLines method. It will load only one line to memory at a time. Use linq to process matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the file once, store it in a variable, because I/O operations are expensive. Then, run the regex on the variable.

When you read your file into a variable, you read it from hard disk to RAM, accessing RAM is fast, hard disk is slow. **Without doubt** best is to read from hard disk once!

Also reading line by line fails, if you want to match multiline pattern.

For example:

```
Can
you
match
me
if
you
read
me
line
by
line?
```

"Can\s+you" regex would fail to match in this case, because you won't get "Can" and "you" in same string.

Comment: There is no need for that because streamreader uses buffer so it wont be that slow even if you read char by char to end

Comment: What I was doing before was reading the whole file each time, but @Saibot is suggesting I read the file once and store it for later.

Comment: @silent He is using a method for reading and running the regex, and each time to run regex he also read file again.

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary Even if StreamReader uses buffer and optimizes I/O operations, it's still far more expensive to read again and again, instead of reading once into the RAM.

Answer (score 2):

`Find` only gets the first match. so if you really want to get the first match dont read whole file. its inefficient. read the file line by line using `File.ReadLines`

Also using `Regex.IsMatch` at every iteration is inefficient. create regex only once.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("regex-query-here");
return File.ReadLines(path).FirstOrDefault(l => regex.IsMatch(l));
```

`File.ReadLines` loads only one line to memory at a time. `FirstOrDefault` will stop iteration as soon as first match is found. so if your match is in 23rd line you will read only 23 lines from the file and you will get your result.

Reading all the file into memory may be faster but thats a trade off between memory and performance.

Another thing i have to mention is that splitting by `\n` is not a cross-platform way to get lines.

Comment: Yeah. Not to mention `Split` and `ToList` calls. +1

Comment: What if the match is partly in one line, partly in the following line. For example: String "Match\nMe" would NOT match regex "\w+\s+\w+" if you read line by line.

Comment: I think your especial case is not problem for OP. he just didnt know to use the right method. the right method is this.

Comment: @Saibot Correct, but that's another story - the OP question is "to get **line** ..."

Comment: No, OP question is to optimize reading. Reading line by line is not optimizing, making it error-prone. The thing has to be done is, without doubt. Reading the file, once and only once, reading again and again is not logical.